# Apps Script API returning 404 error for existing project. Error returned as HTML rather than JSON

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I was attempting to run an Apps Script function using the Apps Script API. I set up the script in the console, and created an oauth client ID for the script. I configured the authorisation screen and deployed the script as API executable. I tested the api function calling in the same script but got a 404 error saying:

The Requested URL /v1/scripts/{{my_script_id}}:run was not found on this server.

The response came back as HTML. I also noticed that the script seems to make it's own client ID when it's called from the API.

I tried disabling and re-enabling the API which didn't work. I think it may be a problem with the calling application not being in the same project but I'm not sure how to do that as the Google documentation is unclear.

```
function trigger(){
  var bogus = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var argument = ["Value0", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5"]; 

  //         https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
  //         https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

 var postRequest = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "headers": { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "function": "setStatus",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "parameters": [argument],
    "devMode": false
 };

  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{{my_script_id}}:run", postRequest);
    Logger.log(response);
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

I expected some form of error in the form of JSON or maybe even for the function to run, what I got was a HTML document which displayed a 404 error when displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You're not `POST`ing the request. Default `.fetch` method is `GET`.

Add this in `postRequest` object:

```
method: "POST",
```

`payload` is also missing from your `postRequest`.

#### Snippet:

```
var postRequest = {
    "method":"POST", //added
    "contentType": "application/json", //key changed
    "headers": { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
     "payload": JSON.stringify({   //added
      "function": "setStatus",
      "parameters": argument, //removed []
      "devMode": false
    })
 };
```

#### References:

- [UrlfetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)
- [Script:run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run#request-body)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's no longer returning HTML. However it is giving this error: 
 
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
 
This is after updating the request as follows:
 
 {
    method: "POST",
    "Content_Type": "application/json",
    "headers": {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "function": "updateStatus",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    parameters: argument
  };
 
 Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: @Tommy `parameters` and other stuff in request body must be in `payload`. Review UrlFetchApp documentation. If you're still having issues after musing the documentation, edit your question with the new code and error or ask a new question.