# How do you pass parameters to a Deployed Google Apps Script API function?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, http-status-code-400, google-apps-script-api

I created a test function (doPost) in a Google Apps Script API using Google Cloud Platform (GCP).  I am now trying to call that function from another script in the same project.

I know I am almost there, because this code works:

```
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var header = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
  "function": "doPost",
  "devMode": true,
};
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": header,
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "payload": {
    "function": "doPost",
    "devMode": true
  }
};

var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:run';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

However, when I try to include a parameter in payload above, it no longer works:

```
  "payload": {
    "function": "doPost",
    "parameters": ['1'],
    "devMode": true
  }
```

Following other stackoverflow answers, I've tried using in the header:

```
  "contentType": 'application/json',
```

And accordingly, for the payload:

```
 "payload": JSON.stringify({
    "function": "doPost",
    "parameters": ['1'],
    "devMode": true
  })
```

Whenever I use "JSON.stringify", even without parameters (just like the situation I got to work), it errors out.

With JSON.stringify (and parameters in the payload), I get a worse error, which seems to say it doesn't like any of the payload:

```
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"function\":\"doPost\",\"parameters\":[1007],\"devMode\":true}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"function\":\"doPost\",\"parameters\":[1007],\"devMode\":true}' could not be found in request message.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"function\":\"doPost\",\"parameters\":[1007],\"devMode\":true}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"function\":\"doPost\",\"parameters\":[1007],\"devMode\":true}' could not be found in request message."
```

Without JSON.stringify (and with parameters in the payload), I get the error:

```
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"parameters\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'parameters' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"parameters\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'parameters' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."
```

Finally, it doesn't matter what I do with parameters.  I'm pretty sure it should be in the format I put above, but I've also tried:

```
"parameters": [1]
"parameters": 1
"parameters": "1"
```

among others.

The doPost script is simple for now:

```
function doPost(parameters) {
  Logger.log('parameters = ' + parameters);
  return "Hello";
}
```

Here is the stackoverflow question that seems to be most like this: [Apps Script API returning 404 error for existing project. Error returned as HTML rather than JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708760/apps-script-api-returning-404-error-for-existing-project-error-returned-as-html), but doesn't seem to answer my problem.

I've studied the scripts.run page about parameters: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run#authorization-scopes, along with many other pages, including the URL Fetch Service: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch.

This is certainly not my first time using UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script, but it is when calling my own GAS API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not long after I posted this, and after continuing to see post after post say that you should use JSON.stringify for the payload and contentType: application/json in the header, in the header I changed:

```
"contentType": "application/json"
```

to

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

and it works now!

Comment: In your question, I couldn't understand about the part that `"contentType": 'application/json'` is put in your script. But from your answer, I thought that you might put it to the request header. About `"contentType": 'application/json'`, you can also use this. But in this case, please include it in `options` instead of `headers` like `var options = {"method": "POST", "headers": header,"contentType": 'application/json',,,`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike!  I see from your reference that if it is in the Options, that it is contentType, but in the header it is Content-Type.  I was trying to put contentType in the header, and that obviously does not work.